# Can we move without moving?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, relative-motion

So here is the question,
If I jump and hover over the ground for sometime why don't we move away from the point I jumped from? Because earth is rotating so if I hover long enough we should move from the point I jumped from.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48287/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137191/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/411206/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of inertia, you continue with the speed that you had in contact with the ground, until you start to slow down but you have to be in the air for sufficient time to allow that to happen and you have the effects of windspeed and air resistance to consider.

This is one of the problems that the snipers, or long range target shooters, face. That the earth continues to rotate while the bullet follows a (relatively) straight path which will be affected by windspeed - which is not constant.

Comment: I forgot to mention not to count the air collision  But i got the point.Thanks.